# Extracting zip Overwrite by default?

Tags: python, zip

I have the following code:

```
pz = open(packagezip, 'rb')

packz = zipfile.ZipFile(pz)
for name in packz.namelist():
    packz.extract(name, package_ext_loc)

pz.close()
```

If the files to extract  from (packagezip) encounter a folder in the destination location (package_ext_loc) with the same name, will this function automaticaly overwrite the folder and files as this **IS** what I want, if not is there a simple additional script to force this to happen.

edit having gone through some websites I believe the zipfile.extractall overwrites if destination folder already exists. how could I use extractall in this example.

Comment: So you wrote the code but you did not run the code to verify the behavior. Instead you chose to ask someone here to run your code. Is that correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tested your code and it works fine. Meaning that each time I run the code it overwrites the same existing file in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

I have gone a round about way of making sure that if there are duplicate folders they are removed like this,

```
packagezip = xbmc.translatePath('special://home/userdata/addon_data/plugin.program.super.favourites/Super Favourites/Maintenance/packages/packages.zip')
userdatapackagezip = xbmc.translatePath('special://home/userdata/addon_data/plugin.program.super.favourites/Super Favourites/Maintenance/packages/addondata.zip')

package_ext_loc = xbmc.translatePath('special://home/addons/')
addondata_ext_loc = xbmc.translatePath('special://home/userdata/addon_data/')
yespackage = os.path.exists(packagezip)
yesaddondata = os.path.exists(userdatapackagezip)

if yespackage:
    xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(New Packages available, Extracting,()")
    pz = open(packagezip, 'rb')
    packz = zipfile.ZipFile(pz)
    for name in packz.namelist():
        addonpath = xbmc.translatePath('special://home/addons/' + name)
        addonpathexists = os.path.exists(addonpath)
        if addonpathexists:
            xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(Previous version exists, removing,()")
            shutil.rmtree(addonpath, ignore_errors=False)
            xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(Please wait, preparing extraction,()")
            time.sleep(3)
            packz.extract(name, package_ext_loc)
            xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(Extracted, REBOOT REQUIRED,()")
        else:
            xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(No previous version, Extracting,()")
            packz.extract(name, package_ext_loc)
            xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(Extracted, REBOOT REQUIRED,()")
    pz.close()
    xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(Packages Extracted, checking addondata,()")

    if yesaddondata:
        xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(Extracting addondata, Please wait!,()")
        adz = open(userdatapackagezip, 'rb')
        paddz = zipfile.ZipFile(adz)
        for name in paddz.namelist():
            addondatapath = xbmc.translatePath('special://home/userdata/addon_data/' + name)
            addondataexists = os.path.exists(addondatapath)
            if addondataexists:
                xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(Previous data folder esists, now removing,()")
                shutil.rmtree(addondatapath, ignore_errors=False)
                xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(Please wait, preparing extraction,()")
                time.sleep(3)
                paddz.extract(name, addondata_ext_loc)
                xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(Extracted, maybe needs Reeboot,()")
            else:
                xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(No previous version, Extracting,()")
                paddz.extract(name, addondata_ext_loc)
        adz.close()
    else:
        xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(No addondata, at this time,()")

else:
    xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(No packages, at this time,()")
    xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(Checking addondata, for extraction,()")
    if yesaddondata:
        xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(Extracting addondata, Please wait!,()")
        adz = open(userdatapackagezip, 'rb')
        paddz = zipfile.ZipFile(adz)
        for name in paddz.namelist():
            addondatapath = xbmc.translatePath('special://home/userdata/addon_data/' + name)
            addondataexists = os.path.exists(addondatapath)
            if addondataexists:
                xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(Previous data folder esists, now removing,()")
                shutil.rmtree(addondatapath, ignore_errors=False)
                xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(Please wait, preparing extraction,()")
                time.sleep(3)
                paddz.extract(name, addondata_ext_loc)
                xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(Extracted, maybe needs Reeboot,()")
            else:
                xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(No previous version, Extracting,()")
                paddz.extract(name, addondata_ext_loc)
        adz.close()
    else:
        xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(No addondata, at this time,()")
```

I wasnt sure if zipfile would overwrite automatically
This kode is for a kodi maintenance addon